# ob_get_clean() is not working on MAMP but works on WampServer?

Tags: php, wamp, mamp, wampserver

Can anyone explain why the following script behaves differently on two different platforms?

Script:

```
<?php

echo "hello!";

$view_content = ob_get_clean();

echo "'".gettype($view_content)."' >".$view_content."<";
```

Output 1 (on WampServer 2i - php v5.3.0 - Windows 7 x64 ):

```
'string' >hello!<
```

Output 2 ( on MAMP 1.9 - php v5.3.2 - OSX 10.6.4 ):

```
hello!'boolean' ><
```

It seems like MAMP is not performing the function 'ob_get_clean()' correctly. I also tried v5.2.13 of php on MAMP and saw the same problem.

I realize that these are different "versions" of php but i feel like this should work.
Is there an extension/module I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably on 1 host, [automatic output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) is on. I'd advise against that, as it hogs resources that are not needed most of the time. You can use & set it if you rely on it, a better way IMHO is to just call `ob_start()` when the *real* need arises.

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php):

> Return Values
>   Returns the contents of the output buffer and end output buffering. If output buffering isn't active then FALSE is returned.

Comment: Thanks wrikken, Is there another way to accomplish the same task that is more efficient and/or elegant?  By 'task', i mean substituting all previous output into some sort of template, demonstrated simply above.  I am using this system in my view templating pattern (MVC).

Comment: Usually, the only reason to buffer output is because you might need to send other headers. The proper solution is to do all you manipulation & dataretrieval first, and after you've got all the data and have sent headers, then start outputting the body of the response. With a proper architecture this is easily achieved. However, if you templating system just echo's/prints out directly to STDOUT, that is a pain. It _should_ IMHO return strings which _you choose_ to echo or store for later. If it all does go to STDOUT, then I'd manually call `ob_start()` functions just prior to execution.